# \begin{} ended by \document{} -

Tags: beamer, pdftex

**Edit:**
Code uploaded here: https://uni-wuppertal.sciebo.de/s/xAqNFbiQor683UA

**Found what is causing the error:**

The Environment bibFrame and contactFrame are defined with the package environ. In this definition, they are set as a Frame. The problem is, that the Beamer-class, with the option ignorenoneframetext set, is not recognizing bibFrame/contactframe as a Frame-Environment.

I get an Error-message while compiling:

`! LaTeX Error: \begin{contactFrame} on input line 136 ended by \end{document}.`

and I really can't find out why.

The Environment `contactframe` is defined in a custom .cls as:

```
\NewEnviron{contactFrame}[7][]{%
        \begin{frame}[plain]{#1}
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
        \resetsize
        \vspace{1.2ex}
        \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
            \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
                \begin{tcolorbox}[
                    enhanced,
                    width=\textwidth,
                    height=\textheight - \doppelrand,
                    arc=0mm,
                    boxrule=0mm,
                    /tcb/size=minimal,
                    watermark graphics=graphics/section.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
                    \vspace{0.5cm}
                    \hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_section}
                    \vspace{1.5cm}
                     {\setstretch{1.0}
                    \begin{center}
                        \huge\color{white}\textbf{\BODY}
                    \end{center}}
                    \setstretch{1.0}
                    {\small
                    \textblockorigin{0pt}{\paperheight}
                    \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}[0,1](\doppelrand, -\doppelrand)
                        \color{white}
                        \textbf{Kontakt} \\
                        {#2} \\
                        {#3} \\
                        {#4} \\
                        {#5} \\
                        {#6} \\
                        {\MYhref{#7}}
                    \end{textblock*}}
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    \end{frame}
}
```

And used in the main file as:

```
\mode<presentation>{
\begin{contactFrame}{\insertauthor}{\insertchair}{\insertorganisation}{\insertaddress}{\insertmail}{\insertwebsite}
    Vielen Dank für die Aufmerksamkeit!
\end{contactFrame}
}
```

If I just press Enter while compiling over command-line, when that error-message comes up, it's working as supposed. `ignoreframetext` Option is activated.

For example, this Environment:

```
% Master Section Frame
\NewEnviron{sectionFrame}[1][]{%
    \begin{frame}[plain]{#1}
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
        \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
        \resetsize{}
        \vspace{1.2ex}
       \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
            \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
                \begin{tcolorbox}[
                    enhanced,
                    width=\textwidth,
                    height=\textheight - \doppelrand,
                    arc=0mm,
                    boxrule=0mm,
                    /tcb/size=minimal,
                    watermark graphics=graphics/section.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
                    \vspace{0.5cm}
                    \hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_section}
                    \vspace{1.5cm}
                    {\setstretch{1.0}
                      \huge\color{white}\textbf{\BODY}
                    }
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    \end{frame}
}
```

called by

```
% fuer jede section eine Titelseite einfuegen
\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{sectionFrame}
        \begin{center}
            \secname
        \end{center}
    \end{sectionFrame}
}
```

it is working just fine and is using the same syntax. If I just copy the Syntax to the bibFrame-definition, I still get the same error message.

Anyone with an idea? Thanks in advance for your time! :)

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is without having to add any code.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded my code. A real minimal example isnt quite easy to do, as it still would be quite long document. If it is still necessary for you being able to help me, i will do it tomorrow as a minimal example.

Comment: please do not use external links. Your question here is archived forever and that link will probably break.

Comment: Yes of course, this was meant as a short workaround, to provide the source. I didnt found a solution, but I found what courses the error - Edited in the Main question post.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to the files, perhaps using a more conventional organization.

There is a small `main.tex` that load`preamble.tex` (not a class) and  `presentation.tex`, the latter between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document`}.

Compiling `main.tex` (pdflatex+ pdflatex + biber + pdflatex + pdflatex)  will produce a presentation of 16 frames, the last being

[image: a]

This is `main.tex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169, ngerman,8pt,covered]{beamer}

\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
    
\input{presentation}
    
\end{document}
```

This is `presentation.tex`

Main changes:

(1) Used `\addbibresource{literatur.bib}` instead of  `\bibliography{literatur.bib}`

(2) Removed option `ignorenonframetext`

```
%% File presentation.tex <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


%In der Präsentation wird nur dargestellt, was in einer Frame Umgebung eingerahmt ist - Oder explizit eingebunden wird.
%Im Skript wird alles dargestellt, dass nicht explizit davon ausgeschlossen wird.
%\mode<all>{...} Wird in Skript und Präsentation eingebunden
%\mode<presentation>{...} Wird nur in der Präsentation eingebunden(Für \maintableofcontents, \sectiontableofcontents, \subsectiontableofcontents, bibFrame, contactFrame zwingend notwendig! - Diese sind nur in der dazugehörigen .cls definiert!)
%\mode<script>{...} Wird ausschließlich im Skript dargestellt.

%Wenn man auf Folien aus der Praesentation zugreifen möchte, die nicht im Skript eingebunden sind, kann man dies mittels: \includeslide[options]{label name} -> Ruft: \pdfimage mit den aufgeführten Optionen auf und bezieht die Folien aus \setjobnamebeamerversion{angegebene Beamer Datei} vornehmen.

\mode<all>{
\title{Eine Vorlage für Präsentationen der CoP IGB/DaL} % Titel
\topic{Titel der Vorlesung} % Untertitel
\footertitle{Footertitle} % Fußzeilentitel

\author{CoP Informatische Grundbildung/Digitalisierung als Lerngegenstand} %Autor/in
\date{\today} %Datum
\mail{cop-igb@lists.uni-due.de} %Mailadresse
\website{https://www.uni-due.de/comein} % optional, wird automatisch in \url{}-Umgebung gesetzt
\organisation{Universität Duisburg-Essen}
\chair{Didaktik der Informatik}
\address{Schützenbahn 70, 45127 Essen}
\license{\ccbysa} % default: \ccbysa, andere Optionen siehe Dokumentation des ccicons-package 
\chairlogo{graphics/ddi-combo.pdf} % Pfad zum einzubindenden Lehrstuhllogo
\slidesurl{https://www.uni-due.de/comein} % Diese URL wird in einen QR-Code übersetzt
}

%\begin{document}
% Titelfolie ->Noch nicht definiert für Skirpt
\mode<presentation>{
\maketitle
}
\newpage

%Ausgabe Literaturverzeichnis Skript:


\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis nur Hauptpunkte}
  \maintableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis nur Hauptpunkte}
  \sectiontableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis nur Hauptpunkte}
  \subsectiontableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\section{Die Standardfolie}

\begin{frame}{Eine einzelne Folie}
Alle geschriebenen Inhalte einer Folie werden standardmaßig linksbündig und vertikal zentriert ausgegeben.
\end{frame}


\section{Zitate}
\begin{frame}{Definition Kompetenz nach \citeauthor{weinert_vergleichende_2001}}
Das Paket \texttt{biblatex} ist mit der Option \texttt{biber} geladen. Es kann also auf alle Befehle dieses Pakets zugegriffen werden. Zitate bitte in die \texttt{\textbackslash enquote\{...\}}-Umgebung setzen, bspw. so:
    \begin{quote}
        \enquote{Dabei versteht man unter Kompetenzen die bei Individuen verfügbaren
            oder durch sie erlernbaren kognitiven Fähigkeiten und Fertigkeiten,
            um bestimmte Probleme zu lösen, sowie die damit verbundenen
            motivationalen, volitionalen und sozialen Bereitschaften und
            Fähigkeiten um die Problemlösungen in variablen Situationen
            erflogreich und verantwortungsvoll nutzen zu können.} Siehe \cite[S.27-28]{weinert_vergleichende_2001}
    \end{quote}
\end{frame}

Eine hier eingefügte Erklärung zu dem Zitat, würde ausschließlich im Skript berücksichtigt werden.


\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis nur Hauptpunkte}
  \sectiontableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\subsection{Der Tullu-Befehl}

\begin{frame}{Der tullu-Befehl}
Mit dem \texttt{tullu}-Befehl können eingebundene Inhalte wie bspw. Bilder referenziert werden.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{graphics/bmbf.pdf}
\caption{\tullu{BMBF-Logo}{Afrank99}{Public Domain}{https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/}{Wikipedia}{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:BMBF_Logo.svg}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\subsubsection{Ein Unter-Unter-Abschnitt}
\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Ein Unter-Unter-Abschnitt}
Diese Folie dient nur der Demonstration von Unter-Unter-Abschnitten.
\end{frame}
}

\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Inhaltsverzeichnis nur Hauptpunkte}
  \subsectiontableofcontents
\end{frame}
}
\section{Zwei Spalten}
\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}{Oder auch mehrere Spalten}
Sie können eine Folie in beliebig viele Spalten unterteilen. Sie müssen lediglich angeben, wie breit jede Spalte sein soll.
\vspace{2em}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Ziel 1.1
                \item Ziel 1.2
                \item Ziel 1.3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        Innerhalb jeder Spalte wird der Text dann wieder linksbündig und vertikal zentriert gesetzt.
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Ziel 2.1
                \item Ziel 2.2
                \item Ziel 2.3
                \item Ziel 2.4
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\mode<script>{%Nur in der Präsentation sinnvoll
\begin{contactFrame}{\insertauthor}{\insertchair}{\insertorganisation}{\insertaddress}{\insertmail}{\insertwebsite}
    Vielen Dank für die Aufmerksamkeit!
\end{contactFrame}
}

\mode<presentation>{%Nur in der Präsentation sinnvoll
\appendix
\begin{bibFrame}[Literaturverzeichnis]
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{bibFrame}
}
%Literaturvrzeichnis fürs Skript:

%%%\end{document}
```

Finally `preamble.tex`

```
% File preamble.tex <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\RequirePackage{qrcode}
\RequirePackage{ccicons}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage[style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=2]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\comein}{COM\textsuperscript{e}IN}

% Bibliographie trimmen
%\bibliography{literatur.bib} %%%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\addbibresource{literatur.bib} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\clearfield{issn} % Remove issn
\clearfield{doi} % Remove doi
\clearfield{eprint}

\ifentrytype{online}{}{% Remove url except for @online
\clearfield{url}
\clearfield{urldate}
\clearfield{urlmonth}
\clearfield{urlyear}
}
}

%Definition der ComeIn-Farben
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{2, 60, 106}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{16, 74, 120}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{30, 86, 133}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{65, 114, 155}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{104, 147, 181}
\definecolor{col6}{RGB}{136, 170, 198}
\definecolor{col7}{RGB}{193, 210, 226}
\definecolor{accent}{RGB}{223,228,242}
\definecolor{text}{RGB}{26,23,27}


%Definition des Randes
\newlength{\rand}
\setlength{\rand}{0.25cm}
\newlength{\doppelrand}
\setlength{\doppelrand}{0.5cm}
\newlength{\lengthleft}
\setlength{\lengthleft}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\lengthleft}{-\doppelrand}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=\doppelrand, text margin right=\doppelrand}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{\rand}}


%Definition zusaetzlicher Angaben fuer die Fusszeile und Titelseite
\newcommand\mail[1]{\def\insertmail{#1}}
\mail{}
\newcommand\chair[1]{\def\insertchair{#1}}
\chair{}
\newcommand\organisation[1]{\def\insertorganisation{#1}}
\organisation{}
\newcommand\address[1]{\def\insertaddress{#1}}
\address{}
\newcommand\website[1]{\def\insertwebsite{#1}}
\website{}
\newcommand\slidesurl[1]{\def\insertslidesurl{#1}}
\slidesurl{}
\newcommand\topic[1]{\def\inserttopic{#1}}
\topic{}
\newcommand\footertitle[1]{\def\insertfootertitle{#1}}
\footertitle{}
\newcommand\license[1]{\def\insertlicense{#1}}
\license{\ccbysa}
\newcommand\chairlogo[1]{\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{chair_logo}{#1}}
\chairlogo{graphics/bmbf.pdf}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=col1,linkcolor=col1,urlcolor=col1}
%%%Definition der Farben von Beamer-Elementen
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{footline}{fg=col1,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white,bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{topic}{fg=white,bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white,bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white,bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{itemize item}{fg=col1}
\setbeamercolor{BlaueBox}{bg=col1}
\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{fg=col1}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}

%Definition der Schriftartdetails
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{topic}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont*{author}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont*{date}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont*{square}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{footline}{size=\footnotesize}

%Definition anderer Standardeinstellungen
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[square]
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\small\raise1.25pt}
\setbeamertemplate*{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\quad}

\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

% Layout fuer die Inhaltsverzeichnisfolie fuer den aktuellen Abschnitt inkl. Unterabschnitten
\newcommand{\sectiontableofcontents}{
\hspace*{\rand}
\begin{minipage}[c][6cm]{\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{minipage}
}

% Definition fuer die Inhaltsuebersicht mit Unter-Unter-Abschnitten
\defbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{subsubsections numbered}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=6em%
\rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}%
\inserttocsubsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

% Layout fuer die Inhaltsverzeichnisfolie fuer den aktuellen Unter-Abschnitt inkl. Unter-Unter-Abschnitten
\newcommand{\subsectiontableofcontents}{
\hspace*{\rand}
\begin{minipage}[c][6cm]{\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide, subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide, subsubsectionstyle=show/show/hide/hide]
\end{minipage}
}

% Layout fuer die Haupt-Inhaltsverzeichnisfolie
\newcommand{\maintableofcontents}{
\hspace*{\rand}
\begin{minipage}[c][6cm]{\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show/show/hide, subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide/hide]
\end{minipage}
}

% Tullu-Command, siehe https://open-educational-resources.de/oer-tullu-regel/
\newcommand{\tullu}[6]{#1 von #2 unter \href{#4}{#3} via \href{#6}{#5}}

%Definition der Logos
\pgfdeclareimage[height=2cm]{comein_logo_titelseite}{graphics/comein.pdf}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.2cm]{comein_logo_section}{graphics/comein.pdf}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.9cm]{bmbf_logo}{graphics/bmbf.pdf}

%Definition eines Templates fuer Titelseite
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

% Layout fuer die Titelseite
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{comein}{%
\vspace{-1.2ex}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight * 2 / 3 - \rand,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
/tcb/size=minimal,
watermark graphics=graphics/title.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
\vspace{2.0cm}
\hfill
\hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_titelseite}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster force size=false,raster column skip=0cm]
\begin{tcolorbox}[
width=.8\textwidth,
height=\textheight * 1 / 3 - \rand,
/tcb/size=small,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
colback=col1]%
\vspace{0.1cm}
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
\parbox{0.96\textwidth}{\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle}\newline
\end{spacing}
\vspace{1ex}
\usebeamerfont{topic}\usebeamercolor[fg]{topic}\inserttopic \newline
\vfill
\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\usebeamerfont{square}$\text{ }\blacksquare$ \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
width=.2\textwidth,
height=\textheight * 1 / 3 - \rand,
/tcb/size=small,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
colback=white]%
\begin{center}
\pgfuseimage{bmbf_logo}\\ 
\pgfuseimage{chair_logo}\\
\insertlicense
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\begin{textblock*}{0.5\textwidth}[0,0](\doppelrand, \doppelrand)
\ifx\insertslidesurl\empty
\else
\usebeamercolor[white]{frametitle}
\textcolor{white}{\qrcode[height=1cm]{\insertslidesurl}}
\fi
\end{textblock*}
}

%Definition des Kopfzeilentemplates
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{comein}{
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
width=\textwidth,
height=1.25cm,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
/tcb/size=minimal,
watermark graphics=graphics/comein_header, watermark stretch=1]%
\hspace{0.2cm}
\parbox[c][1.25cm]{0.7\lengthleft}{%
\begin{spacing}{1.1}
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[white]{frametitle}\insertframetitle
\end{spacing}
}
\hfill 
\end{tcolorbox}
\textblockorigin{\textwidth}{0pt}
\begin{textblock*}{2pt}[1,1](\rand,\rand)
\tiny \color{col1} \insertframenumber{}
\end{textblock*}
\end{minipage}
}%
}

\makeatletter
%Definition des Fusszeilentemplates
\newcommand{\comein@footline}{
\parbox{0.32\textwidth}{\pgfuseimage{chair_logo}}
\parbox{0.32\textwidth}{\centering\insertdate \\ \insertlicense}
\parbox{0.32\textwidth}{\hfill \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\insertmail{} \\
\insertfootertitle{}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}
}
\makeatother
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{comein}{%
\ifnum \insertframenumber=1
\else
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=0.5cm]{white}
\usebeamerfont{footline}\comein@footline
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\fi
}

% Groessen fuer Kopf- und Fusszeilen wieder zuruecksetzen
\newcommand*{\resetsize}{\csname beamer@calculateheadfoot\endcsname}

% Befehl zum Setzen der Titelfolie
\def\maketitle{\frame{\titlepage}\resetsize}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[comein]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[comein]

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

% Unterabschnitte einruecken
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.2em\rlap{\hskip-2em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[comein]{}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight - \rand,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
/tcb/size=minimal,
watermark graphics=graphics/section.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_section}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\huge\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\insertsection}}
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}
}


% Master Section Frame
\NewEnviron{sectionFrame}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}[plain]{#1}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\resetsize{}
\vspace{1.2ex}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight - \doppelrand,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
/tcb/size=minimal,
watermark graphics=graphics/section.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_section}
\vspace{1.5cm}
{\setstretch{1.0}
\huge\color{white}\textbf{\BODY}
}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}%
\end{frame}
}

% Master Bib Frame
%%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\NewEnviron{bibFrame}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{#1}
\BODY
\end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[1]{\href{#1}{\color{white}{\texttt{#1}}}}%

% Master Contact Frame
\NewEnviron{contactFrame}[7][]{%
\begin{frame}[plain]{#1}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\resetsize
\vspace{1.2ex}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\rand\relax}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
width=\textwidth,
height=\textheight - \doppelrand,
arc=0mm,
boxrule=0mm,
/tcb/size=minimal,
watermark graphics=graphics/section.jpg, watermark stretch=1]%
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hfill \pgfuseimage{comein_logo_section}
\vspace{1.5cm}
{\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{center}
\huge\color{white}\textbf{\BODY}
\end{center}}
\setstretch{1.0}
{\small
\textblockorigin{0pt}{\paperheight}
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}[0,1](\doppelrand, -\doppelrand)
\color{white}
\textbf{Kontakt} \\
{#2} \\
{#3} \\
{#4} \\
{#5} \\
{#6} \\
{\MYhref{#7}}
\end{textblock*}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
}%
\end{frame}
}

% fuer jede section eine Titelseite einfuegen
\AtBeginSection{
\begin{sectionFrame}
\begin{center}
\secname
\end{center}
\end{sectionFrame}
}
```

Used Version biber 2.17 (biblatex 3.17)

Comment: First of all, I want to say: Thank you for the time you put into this! We are using the Beamer class, because we want to create a script and the presentation from the same main file. So there is another .cls defined for the script - That's why the uncommon file structure is there. I didn't uploaded the comein_skript.cls and skript.tex, as I dont have any trouble with them. For using the script Version, I need to use the ignorenoneframetext option together with the packages fullpage/beamerarticle